# How can I share an image from Firebase to Whatsapp, Instagram etc (Android Studio)

Tags: android, image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-viewholder

I want to share an Image in my app from Firebase to Whatsapp, Facebook etc.

I want that I can share the Image if I click on it.

This is my ViewHolder:

```
public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    View mView;
    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView= itemView;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ImageView content = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewy);
                content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
                try {
                    cachePath.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                    ostream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/*");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(cachePath));
                v.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share via"));

            }




        });

    }
```

At first it is working, if I click on the Image I can chose where I want to share the Image. Then, if I chose Whatsapp it says "Sharing failed, please try again"

Am I doing something wrong? Please tell me how I can solve this.

I also tried this code:

```
public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        View mView;
        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView= itemView;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    ImageView content = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewy);
                    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                    Bitmap icon = content.getDrawingCache();
                    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    share.setType("image/jpeg");
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
                    try {
                        f.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
                    v.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));

                }




            });
    }
```

Comment: in first code change `share.setType("image/jpeg")` try this one

Comment: @RajeshRajendiran No this is also not working.

Comment: check `Uri.fromfile(file)`

Comment: @RajeshRajendiran what should I check there?

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView content = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewy);    
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Uri imageUri= Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), content, "title", "discription"));
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

as this document suggests https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send,
MediaStore is suitable for sharing content.

Note that once added to the system MediaStore the content is accessible to any app on the device.

and ofc you will need storage permission as well.